# How to access index in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to access indices instead of element value

```
import numpy as np

data=np.arange(20,60)
def number_of_dies_probed(inp_arr)-> np.array:

    inp_arr=inp_arr.flatten()
    enter_numbers=int(input('Enter number of dices to be probed:'))#for example input value 8
    vb=((len(inp_arr))/enter_numbers)

    dies_to_probe=(inp_arr[np.arange(0,inp_arr.shape[0],int(vb))])
    return dies_to_probe
mn=number_of_dies_probed(data)
print(mn)
```

current output:

```
 [20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55]
```

requirement:instead of element values I need index values like this below.
required output:

```
[0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35]
```

Comment: You already have the index values - `np.arange(0,inp_arr.shape[0],int(vb))`

I don't understand why you are then indexing the array `inp_arr[ .... ]` if you don't want the element values.

Comment: Because  Indexing done according to dimensions, for an example,in the first move the chicken moves from one to 10 points. each point(index) have food. Chiken eat each time idiffernt amount of food (values).
second move also same points(index) but different food consumption (values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return np.in1d(inp_arr, dies_to_probe).nonzero()[0]

returns:
array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35], dtype=int64)
```